# How do you to detect a drop in connection from the client with Spring Webflux and Reactor Netty?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm dealing with an issue where I'm not able to surface any kind of error exception my server is disconnected from my client. I want my code to be able to detect that the client no longer has a connection with the server but nothing I'm trying is working. doOnError, doOnCancel, doFinally all are not able to surface anything.

```
    @Override
    public <T> Flux<T> select(Query query, Class<T> entityClass) throws DataAccessException 

        return client.post()
                .uri("/query-stream")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("{\"sql\": \"" + sqlQuery + "\"}"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class)
                .skip(1)
                .<T>handle((jsonString, sink) -> handleJsonResponse(jsonString,entityClass, sink))
                .doOnError(this::handleError)
                .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("Cancel connection"))
                .doFinally(signalType -> {
                    if (signalType == SignalType.CANCEL) {
                        System.out.println("Cancel Signal");
                    }
                });

    }
```

```
        ksqlDbEntityTemplate.select(null, String.class)
                .subscribe(System.out::println,
                error -> {
                    // Handle errors
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    latch.countDown(); // Release the latch in case of an error.
                }, latch::countDown
        );
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this, but do yo want to detect an error condition when you disconnect. Why?

Comment: My client is connected to a server. Whenever that server goes down or if there is any disruption of any kind, I want my client to be able to surface an exception. Currently, no exception or error has surfaced, it seems like my http call which is a stream just long polls without recognizing there is any interruption.

Comment: Well, nothing is detected unless there's a communication attempt. Try sending something--if no answer the connection is probably down.

Comment: I am running a ksqlDB push query which polls the endpoint and listens for any changes, so it is always listening for any new events with records, shouldnt my subscription be able to detect if this connection was closed?

Comment: Yes, if the TCP connection is closed according to the rules, your client should be able to detect that. But that is not always the case, and you need to handle it.

Comment: yes thats what i am asking, how do I handle it? The methods that I posted about is not handling it currently.

Comment: Hmm, well, may be I was stuck on "when I disconnect my client manually". What does it mean and why do you want some error  diagnosis in these cases?

Comment: I wan't to be able to surface an error to get a notification of some kind and trigger a retry to reconnect to the server so I can keep ingesting any data into my application.

Comment: Ok. got it. So you need some kind of watchdog mechanism. If it's not available in your libraries you need to implement it yourself. Sorry for taking up your time ;)

Comment: What about TCP keep alive? Sometimes the connections are dropped silently and TCP keep-alive can help. See for more info https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#connection-timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with the TCP Keep alive mechanism seems to be the only options here which works for us. After the kernel's designated TCP Keep Alive time is exceeded, and exception is thrown and we can act off of that exception.